# How to name the device in Apache IoTDB that needs to be checked in tree modelling?

Tags: function, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When do modeling in Apache IoTDB, suppose there are 10 devices in the factory and each device has 6 measuring points. If the device name is meaningful to be checked in using scenarios, and the model may name like `root.factory.equipmentnumber.measuringpoint`, how should the device name be set? How should we consider which measurement point should be associated with tags or attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `root.factory.tag1.tag2.tagN.equipment number.measuring point` in Apache IoTDB to see if querying directly using time series name can deal with your using scenarios.